# Changing navigation bar color inMFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Going a little stir crazy trying to figure out why I can't change the background color of this controller...it changes the text, not the background...what am I missing?

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    // set nav bar color
    UIColor *titleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 20.0/255.0 green: 33.0/255.0 blue:61.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
    [mailer.navigationBar setTintColor:titleColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTintColor:` is the method for setting the bar color on iOS6 and lower. On iOS7+, use `setBarTintColor:`.

Answer (score 0):

In your App Delegate's `-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching`, you should include the line:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 20.0/255.0 green: 33.0/255.0 blue:61.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0]];
```

Then, all navigation bars throughout your application will have that tint color. The UIAppearance class is really powerful and works for customizing most UI elements

Note: This is only compatible with iOS 5+

Comment: Thanks..I did see that, but I use two different colors based on where the user is in the application...I use blue for normal views and red for settings views...so I'm trying to change this single view to red to match the others.